# XQuery function: variable and expression vs FLOWR

Tags: syntax, xquery

**Method 1**

```
declare function foo($bar){
     variable $x := some_fn($bar/yada/yada);
     variable $y := other_fn($x);
     $y
};
```

**Method 2 (FLOWR)**

```
declare function foo($bar){
     let $x := some_fn($bar/yada/yada)
     let $y := other_fn($x)
     return $y
};
```

Different syntax, same result; from the processor's point of view, what's different? What reasons are there to prefer one method over the other?  For readability, I prefer the FLOWR.

Comment: I'm not sure the first method is technically valid XQuery. AFAIK variable declarations should only occur in the Prolog, and they also require `declare`. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#id-variable-declarations What XQuery processor are you using?

Comment: I use both Saxon and Zorba

Comment: @wst are you referring to this? "A variable declaration always refers to a declaration of a variable in a Prolog. The binding of a variable to a value in a query expression, such as a FLWOR expression, is known as a variable binding, and does not make the variable visible to an importing module."

Comment: Right, and that section also outlines the proper syntax. I think Zorba is too lax with syntax, and that's probably a Zorba bug. If you declare `xquery version "3.0";` it should conform to the spec. If Zorba wants to extend the spec, they should probably require something like `xquery version "3.0-zorba";` to use it. I haven't tested in Saxon, but are you sure this works? Saxon is usually very good at spec compliance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first method (using `variable`) relies on non-standard extensions. At least on Zorba, this is called the [Zorba Scripting Extension](http://www.zorba.io/documentation/latest/zorba/scripting_tutorial/) (scroll to the bottom, header "Scripting") which adds side-effecting imperative programming constructs to XQuery. This extension is on in Zorba by default but [can be turned off](http://www.zorba.io/documentation/latest/zorba/specifications/options_and_annotations).

I cannot find a specification for this extension. To add to the confusion, there is a W3C XQuery extension called the [XQuery Scripting Extension](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-sx-10/) which adds the same feature but with a *different* syntax and Zorba *does not* implement this W3C extension. The W3C syntax is [`declare $x ...;`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-sx-10/#prod-xquery-BlockVarDecl) (instead of `variable $x ...;` at the top of a block.

Anyway, here are the differences between your two code snippets:

1. Your `variable` method is non-standard and possibly Zorba-specific; your FLWOR is vanilla XQuery 1.0.
2. The `variable` method is side-effecting: `$x` and `$y` are in-scope in the entire block and can be re-assigned at any moment. With the FLWOR method, each `let` binding is only visible to the following FLWOR clauses.
3. I don't know if there are any performance implications for such a simple example. Speaking very generally, sometimes mutability and side-effects are faster, but such code is usually harder for compilers to optimize (and they might be able to optimize immutable pure code better than hand-written mutable code). But this completely depends on what Zorba does under the hood.

I would not use `variable` because it is non-standard and because I prefer the predictability of expression-based, non-imperative code. Making XQuery imperative sounds like a misfeature to me.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer.  Follow up question-- when we want to calculate something one time for use in a subsequent FLOWR loop (e.g. suppose there is a FLOWR after "variable $y..." in Method 1)-- is it necessary just to nest FLOWR expressions?

Comment: You might be able to chain more `let`s to the end of a single FLWOR, or you can put the final expression in the `return` clause, but generally you nest FLWOR expressions. You can open a question with a more specific example if this advice is too general.

Answer (score 0):

As @wst commented, your first example isn't valid XQuery. The `variable` keyword is only valid in a variable declaration, which must be in the query prolog:

```
declare variable $a := "a";
```

I don't have Saxon handy, but I tested something similar to your example in MarkLogic, Zorba, and eXistDB, and each threw syntax errors.

Comment: Maybe you can post what threw a syntax error in Zorba; I use Zorba and I have quite a collection of functions which use "variable" up top, none of which produce syntax errors.